# Gulp task to create source maps affects all files, not just the ones that have changed

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to come up with a `gulp` task that generates new source maps whenever its corresponding `.js` file has changed, this is what I have so far:

```
gulp.task('maps', [ 'compile:ts' ], function () {
   return gulp.src([
         'app/**/*.js'
     ])
  .pipe(newer({ dest: 'app', ext: '.js.map' }))
  .pipe(print(function (filepath) {
     return 'Creating source map for ' + filepath + '...';
  }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(print(function (filepath) {
     return 'Writing source map for ' + filepath + '...';
  }))
  .pipe(checkout())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
  ;
});
```

Now two weird things happen:

- `gulp-newer` returns all `.js` files, it doesn't matter if they were changed or not (regarding the timestamps of the `.map.js` files).
- `gulp-sourcemaps` emits both, the `.js` and the `.js.map` file.

Can anyone provide a hint what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `gulp-sourcemaps` emits both, the `.js` and the `.js.map` file.

That's to be expected, because [that's how source maps work](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/#toc-howwork). Each `.js` file contains a `sourceMappingURL` comment that points to the `.js.map` file so your browser knows where to find it.

You can leave this out by using the [`addComment` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps#write-options):

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'), {addComment:false})
```

Of course, that means your HTTP server has to send a `X-SourceMap` header for each `.js` file.

> `gulp-newer` returns all `.js` files, it doesn't matter if they were changed or not (regarding the timestamps of the `.map.js` files).

This might be caused by `gulp-sourcemaps` emitting both a `.js` and a `.js.map` file, effectively overwriting your existing `.js` file. Using the same source and destination directories is generally a bad idea, so using a different `dest` directory would solve this problem.

(It might also be caused by the `checkout()` pipe, but you didn't describe what that does. I'd try removing this and see if it works.)

However I don't think any of the above really matters, since your general approach and the way you're using `gulp-sourcemaps` is likely to be completely wrong. I assume you want sourcemaps from your original `.ts` files to your compiled `.js` files. In that case you need to use it in your `compile:ts` task. The way you're using it now will just produce an empty source map file.

Comment: `checkout` is `gulp-tfs-checkout` and you're right, I'm trying to create maps for my `.ts` files. I'll check back later when I'm at work.